# App crashing in iPhone

Tags: ios, uitableview

After I implement pull to refresh in UITableView, then I tried 4 to 5 times my app crashing ...

EXC_BAD_ACCESS on setImage.

```
cell.thumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage.png"];

dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

    NSString *imageURL = [currentArticle objectForKey:@"Image"];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [cell.thumbnail setImage:image];

    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure what's wrong here, but for this issue it's good to use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage, great stuff, totally recommend.

Comment: Where are the crash logs? Would you mind showing the logs?